# Как показать большую панель навигации при переходе в другой контроллер?

Tags: ios, swift, navigationbar

В `storyboard` у меня есть `NavigationController`, связанный с `FirstTableVC`, переходящий к `SecondTableVC`. Я хочу, чтобы во всех моих контроллерах была большая панель навигации. Но когда я прокручиваю вниз «FirstTableVC» и перехожу к «SecondTableVC», моя панель навигации обычного размера. Как это исправить?

код в `FirstTableVC`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .black
        title = "FirstTableVC"
    }
```

код в `SecondTableVC`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        title = "SecondTableVC"
    }
```

**Что у меня сейчас:**

[image]

**Что я хочу получить:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Добавить в viewDidLoad:

```
view.addSubview(UIView())
```

А в viewDidAppear удалить эту UIView.

Comment: Не помогает....

Comment: А вы пробовали подобное делать? У вас работает? Можете поделиться проектом... Может я что-то не так делал...

Answer (score 0):

В первом контроллере сделайте:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
    }
```

Во втором контроллере:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    }
```

Comment: Не помогает....

Comment: У Вас это решение работает в каком либо Xcode проекте?

Comment: Добрый день! Да, работает.

Comment: Посмотрите, пожалуйста, мой тестовый проект - https://gofile.io/d/9MCZ9x . Что я не так делаю? Мне в первом контроллере тоже нужен `prefersLargeTitles = true` он во всех контроллерах должен быть Large

Comment: class FirstViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .black
        title = "FirstTableVC"
    } Во втором контроллере можете все удалить. Если я Вас правильно понял, у Вас всегда должен быть высокая навигация при переходе, а не прокрутке таблицы.

Comment: Смотрите как должно быть: когда мое приложение запускается у меня на экране высокая навигация, потом я скроллю вниз по таблице и навигация становится стандартного размера. Далее я нажимаю на ячейку и перехожу во второй контроллер тоже с высокой навигацией.